# replace cell with string if row sums zero in python : not working as expected when looping over list of dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a command that works to replace all columns in a single row, where the entire row consists of only zeros or nans. it works if i do it as a command for a single dataframe, but the behaviour changes when i loop it over a list of dataframes, and gives the wrong output. I cannot understand why this is happening, or how to fix it. some data and the code with examples is below. Any advice would be really great. thanks so much

dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':['a','b','c','d'],'a': [np.nan, 2, 0, np.nan], 'b': [np.nan,2,np.nan, np.nan], 'c': [np.nan,1,0, np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':['a','b','c','d'],'a': [np.nan, 2, 0, np.nan], 'b': [0,2,4, np.nan], 'c': [0,1,0, np.nan]})
```

which gives the following data frames

```
df1
   x    a    b    c
0  a  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  b  2.0  2.0  1.0
2  c  0.0  NaN  0.0
3  d  NaN  NaN  NaN

df2
   x    a    b    c
0  a  NaN  0.0  0.0
1  b  2.0  2.0  1.0
2  c  0.0  4.0  0.0
3  d  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This command will work when running over single dataframes and give the following output

```
df1.loc[~df1.fillna(0).ne(0).all(axis=1), df1.columns != 'x'] = 'test'

      x     a     b     c
0     a  test  test  test
1     b   2.0   2.0   1.0
2     c  test  test  test
3     d  test  test  test
```

but if i loop it like this, then the output is incorrect, the second dataframe is just a replica of the first

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i].loc[~dfs[i].fillna(0).ne(0).all(axis=1), dfs[i].columns != 'x'] = 'test'
```

output i am getting

```
[   x     a     b     c
 0  a  test  test  test
 1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
 2  c  test  test  test
 3  d  test  test  test,
    x     a     b     c
 0  a  test  test  test
 1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
 2  c  test  test  test
 3  d  test  test  test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to 'loc' before your condition. Select rows and columns are two independent operations:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
for df in dfs:
    df.loc[df.loc[:, df.columns != 'x'].fillna(0).eq(0).all(axis=1),
           df.columns != 'x'] = 'test'
```

```
>>> df1
   x     a     b     c
0  a  test  test  test
1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
2  c  test  test  test
3  d  test  test  test

>>> df2
   x     a     b     c
0  a  test  test  test
1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
2  c   0.0   4.0   0.0
3  d  test  test  test
```

Comment: thank you so much this has helped me understand where I am going wrong! This is almost perfect! but its still overwriting the x column which should be retained with !='x'

Comment: I fixed my answer. *Select rows and columns are two independent operations*.  This is right for me too :-P

Comment: thats intersting! I was trying to insert the != in at the beginning or the end, not both! thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':['a','b','c','d'],'a': [np.nan, 2, 0, np.nan], 'b': [np.nan,2,np.nan, np.nan], 'c': [np.nan,1,0, np.nan]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':['a','b','c','d'],'a': [np.nan, 2, 0, np.nan], 'b': [0,2,4, np.nan], 'c': [0,1,0, np.nan]})

for df in [df1,df2]:

```
for (columnname,columndata) in df.iteritems():

    df[columnname]=df[columnname].fillna('test')

    df[columnname]=df[columnname].replace(0,'test')

print(df)
```

Pls simplify more as per your requirement.